# How to change only year when year value is 25 then only we should change. And I have to change it for a file in as400. Date format mm/dd/yy

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have to change the year value to 39 from 25. And the date format is mm/dd/yy. I have to write a sql statement in as400 green screen.
Update matdevdta/filename set fieldname = value where fieldname = value1

I tried to do this
Update matdevdta/filename set fieldname = dateadd(year,13,fieldname) where year(fieldname) = 25
But is showing error like
Column or global variable YEAR not found.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the field is an actual date data type...
And that "green screen" means you are using the interactive STRSQL...

Then you need to realize that Db2 always stores it with a 4 digit year.
It would behoove you to display/work with dates in ISO format.

F13=Services --> 1. Change session attributes -->
Date format  . . . . . . . . .   *ISO

Now a `SELECT * from mytable` will show you dates formatted as `yyyy-mm-dd`

`dateadd()` is not a function available on Db2 for IBM i.  Make sure you are using the correct [SQL Reference](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=reference-sql)

But all you really need is

```
update mytable
set fieldname = fieldname + 14 years
where year(fieldname) = 2025
```

assuming that 2025 --> 2039 is what you're really asking for.  If you really want xx25 --> xx39 then

```
update mytable
set fieldname = fieldname + 14 years
where mod(year(fieldname),100) = 25
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much. I’ve got the answer from my superior. He helped me and he used the same format you mentioned. Dateadd is not available as you said.